# Reading MatLab files in python w/ scipy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm using python w/ scipy package to read the MatLab file.

However it takes too long and crashes.

The [Dataset](http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/RealityMining.zip) is about 50~ MB in size

Is there any better way to read the data and form an edge list ?

My python code

```
import scipy.io as io
data=io.loadmat('realitymining.mat')
print data
```

Comment: No errors. Just that it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Your question says "it crashes".

Comment: How was the file created?  Can you post it somewhere?

Comment: http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/RealityMining.zip

Comment: It crashes most of the time. Produces output rarely. @DanielR

Comment: It is that slow because the mat is compressed. Unpacked to the workspace, it is a 880MB structure. Is enough memory available? Expect that the import takes about twice the memory.

Comment: Just a suggestion in the future: Use HDF5 for large datasets. Matlab has support functions for it, and Python has awesome support in the form of PyTables.

Comment: @JasonS I'll try HDF5

Comment: Uncompressed the `reality...mat` is 57M.  Loading it takes more the 2 min on my machine. But i can save the `['s']` array with `np.save`, producing a larger 251M file.  That loads with `np.load` in 22 sec.

Comment: I have processed the data set. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could just save each field of the struct in a different text file, eg:

```
save('friends.txt', '-struct', 'network', 'friends', '-ascii')
```

and load each file separately from python

```
friends = numpy.loadtxt('friends.txt')
```

which loads instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I can load it after unzipping.  But it is stretching the memory.

When I try to load it with `octave` I get:

```
octave:1> load realitymining.mat
error: memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index type -- trying to return to prompt
```

In Ipython

```
In [10]: data.keys()
Out[10]: ['network', 's', '__version__', '__header__', '__globals__']
In [14]: data['__header__']
Out[14]: 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI, Created on: Tue Sep 29 20:13:23 2009'
In [15]: data['s'].shape
Out[15]: (1, 106)
In [17]: data['s'].dtype
Out[17]: dtype([('comm', 'O'), ('charge', 'O'), ('active', 'O'), ('logtimes', 'O'),...  
   ('my_intros', 'O'), ('home_nights', 'O'), ('comm_local', 'O'), ('data_mat', 'O')])
# 58 fields
In [24]: data['s']['comm'][0,1].shape
Out[24]: (1, 30)
In [31]: data['s']['comm'][0,1][0,1]
Out[31]: ([[732338.8737731482]], [[355]], [[-1]], [u'Packet Data'], [u'Outgoing'], 
    [[40]], [[nan]])
In [33]: data['s']['comm'][0,1]['date']
Out[33]: 
array([[array([[ 732338.86915509]]), array([[ 732338.87377315]]),
    ...
    array([[ 732340.48579861]]), array([[ 732340.52778935]])]], dtype=object)
```

Look at the pieces.  Simply trying to `print data` or `print data['s']` takes too long.  Apparently it is just too big of structure to format quickly.

To practically get at this data, I'd suggest loading it once in Python or Matlab, and then save the useful pieces to one or more files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first work on part of he data as the `network` in the struct, I have unpacked it [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/YocxdBlY/network.html) using MATLAB.

Still working on how to tidy up the rest bigger struct.