# scipy.io.loadmat() is not returning dictionary

Tags: python, scipy

I've been trying to process the reality mining dataset with scipy.

The loadmat() method is not returning a dictionary.

Python code 
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1800572/blog/parse_network.py

Dataset: http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/RealityMining.zip

I get this error when I run the script on the dataset.
AttributeError (numpy.void) my_hashedNumber no such attribute.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? There are many good debuggers: pdb, pudb, ipdb, etc.

Comment: Why are you using Dropbox to post code? o_O

Comment: At least give us part of the error stack.  At what line in your script is this `AttributeError` arising?  The only place that treats the loaded object as a dictionary is: `def get_events(matlab_obj):... subjects = matlab_obj["s"][0]`

Comment: Have you been able to replicate my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573239/reading-matlab-files-in-python-w-scipy/20579060#20579060 ?

Comment: Please remove the link to Dropbox, and paste the appropriate snippet here. This is so the question is not dependent on brittle external links for future readers. Same goes for the sample really: put a few rows in a table here instead. Most readers will not download either as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think this a `loadmat` object not having a dictionary?  The error is at:

```
def get_events(matlab_obj):
    ...
    subjects = matlab_obj["s"][0]
    ...
    for subject_object in subjects:
        try:
            subject_hash = subject_object.my_hashedNumber[0][0]  # AttributeError here
```

`matlab_obj["s"]` successfully accesses the loaded object as a dictionary.  `subjects` is a numpy record array of shape `(106,)`, and 58 fields. The correct way to access one of those fields is: `subject_object['my_hashedNumber']`.

If the field is multidimensional it should be indexed with `[0,0]`, not `[0][0]`.